# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Unknown Module

Tags: c#

I am regularly encountering errors of type **"An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Unknown Module.".** This happens in a website with a quite large code base. But the error occurs only after several minutes of the website.

This is where the error pointed me to:

```
public partial class HealthInsurance : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            Page.Header.DataBind();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not call the base class' implementation of [OnLoad()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.onload.aspx) from an autowired `Page_Load()` handler.

Under the hood, `OnLoad()` is responsible for invoking `Page_Load()`, so your code ends up in an infinite recursive loop.

You only have to write:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Header.DataBind();
}
```

Things would be different had you chosen to override `OnLoad()` rather than rely on `Page_Load()`. In that case, you indeed have to call the base class' method:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    Page.Header.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are subscribing to the `Load` event, do not call the base `OnLoad` as the base `OnLoad` is what's responsible for firing the `Load` event, so it will be an endless cycle.

However, if you are *overriding* the `OnLoad` method, then it's appropriate to call the base `OnLoad` method, e.g.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    Page.Header.DataBind();
}
```

In the above case, note the `override` keyword.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments,l really appreciate. l tried the method you all said but still am having this error again: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: I tried changing the code like this   `protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            //Page.Header.DataBind();}` and it works but it those not show the sidebar. any help!!!!!!